# Purely Vs Absolutely

Tags: word-usage

I came across a question that goes as “ The older generation has  ...... no conception of the many forms that gambling takes now” and among the options were “purely” and “ absolutely “,  both of which sounded just fine to me.
Could anyone explain why I can’t use “purely” in the given sentence please?

Comment: It just sounds strange. We say "I have absolutely no idea", not "I have purely no idea"...

Comment: I understand, thank you 

Comment: "Purely" includes the meaning of "only" because it comes from the word "pure". "... ***only** no conception of*..." makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

### In English, the phrase "*purely no*" is never used.

[image: google ngram for "purely no" and "absolutely no"]